# Does deleting .dll files from system32 directory frees RAM?

Tags: memory, dll

Deleting dlls is never a good idea but I show some dll files in the System32 directory prefixed "QT". I uninstalled QT creator three months ago so I think these are useless here (although, I moved all those dll's in another drive in case if some other apps built using qt require them in the future.). Now I want to know, do I have any memory benefit by doing that. Does it frees RAM?

Comment: An application should never place DLLs in that path anyway. If you like, you could report a bug with Qt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> do I have any memory benefit by doing that. Does it frees RAM?

No. **Unused** files on disk do not use any RAM.

This assumes that they are unused.  It is possible that your OS (an unspecified version of windows) also has files which start with QT and that removing them will break something in yout setup.

> I uninstalled QT creator

This should have cleaned up all its files, though some uninstaller scripts are not well written.  You could try to clean up using a third party uninstaller, but since unused files do not use any RAM I suggest leaving them alone.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. DLL's are only called when needed and are not in use otherwise. The reason their location is in the SYSTEM32 folder, is because this folder has been dedicated as shared dll folder. Basically because many programs can use the same libraries, it would take lots of space if these programs install the same library over and over again. To combat this, Microsoft dedicated a place where the libraries are stored so they can be shared.

Normally the uninstaller knows if a library is used by other software upon uninstalling and if this is the case, the uninstaller leaves the library behind. Unfortunately, its not always the case that this is being done, as it is up to the developer to properly code the uninstaller and there are many uninstaller wizards, some don't actually do this properly.

That explained, all it does it take up diskspace, and its only in memory when they are actually being loaded by software first.

Comment: And even when "loaded", only the code actually used will be brought into RAM. Despite the name of the "LoadLibrary" API, DLLs aren't really loaded. They're _mapped._ Mapping creates a relationship between pages of virtual address space and contents of the DLL, but it doesn't read the DLL into RAM. That only happens when you run routines from the DLL, and only the pages containing the routines  you actually run have to be read in ("faulted in", in the vernacular).